Help Identifying 80s TV Movie About The Year 2000
I'm trying to id a movie I saw as a kid in the mid-80s.  I'm pretty sure it is a made-for-TV movie.  It was an ensemble piece about the coming of the year 2000, showing what various people were doing on Dec 31, 1999.  In one scene, a doctor struggles in the OR to keep a woman alive, saying he had promised her she'd see the new century.  It is not Strange Days.

Never mind, I found it myself. It is ABC's Generation from 1985.



